# Changes made by dconf-tools are lost when logging off

Tags: 11.10, unity, notification-area, dconf, system-tray

I'm trying to get the Wicd tray icon to show up in 11.10 Unity desktop.

When I use dconf editor to add 'Wicd' to the whitelist in Unity>panel, it shows the change but after I log off and then log on the Wicd icon is not in the tray.  When I open dconf editor, the change I made is gone.

Trying sudo dconf or gksu dconf opens some other application.

Is dconf broken?

Addendum: I have discovered that the configuration file (~/.conf/dconf/user) is changed when when ever I use dconf editor to change it, but it is also changed when logging on after logging off.  Apparently some do-gooder process reverts it to default without notifying you.

Time to file a bug?  Perhaps [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/d-conf/+bug/878606)?

Comment: Blindly putting `sudo` in front of a command isn't smart. Please add the output of `ls -al ~/.config/dconf/` to your question.

Comment: Why did you say "Blindly putting sudo in front of a command isn't smart."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed.  This [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/d-conf/+bug/878606) in unity causes the ~/.config/dconf/user file to be overwritten with the default version.

No workaround is available.

Update:  Changes are no longer overwritten.

Comment: That bug has nothing to do with the user file being reset to defaults

Answer (score 0):

dconf sets the configuration but doesn't insure an application is running. Click the gear icon in the upper right and select "Startup Applications...". Make sure wicd is in this list and checked to run. Use the Add button if it isn't. If you still have a problem there may be interference between nm-applet which is installed by the system and wicd. I've no direct experience with wicd but have had interference problems when running a different network manger application.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...  "wicd-gtk" was in startup but "wicd" was not.  I added "wicd" but no joy.  Apparently as noted in the question`s addendum the conf is reset to default when logging out or logging in.  Network manager has been uninstalled from the system, so I assume nm-applet is not running, but we all know the basis for assume.